# Rebasing subtree merges

Tags: git

I was wondering today if it is possible to rebase a subtree merge in Git. Lets assume I have the following situation:

```
-O-R-I-G---------merge-S-O-M-E-M-O-R-E
               /
-S-U-B-T-R-E-E-
```

I would like to leave ORIG as it is and only rebase along SOMEMORE and then into SUBTREE. When I run an interactive rebase like:

```
git rebase -i <commit>
```

where < commit > is some commit inside subtree, then git presents me with several thousand commits that also include orig. So is it possible what I want to? And if so, then how can I do it?

Note that subtree and orig have no common parent as they originate from different repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Rebase is not the best choice in this case.
I think you may need to get individual commits using "cherry-pick"

`git cherry-pick <commit>`

Comment: I believe cherry-picking is not applicable in this case, as I want to interactively rebase the commits to make changes to them. Such as dropping a commit from subtree.